# What Azure regions does Azure Managed Cache support?

Tags: azure, azure-caching

I am running into a weird error:

I have a cache in "West US". I was able to create it successfully.

But it does not let me configure it. I got the following error:

```
The region you chose isn't supported
```

Comment: How did you create it? You can't longer create it in the management portal. But it is still possible using powershell:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2014/05/15/step-by-step-instruction-for-creating-managed-cache-namespace-using-windows-azure-powershell-cmdlets.aspx. Maybe you can edit the cache with powershell too.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to configure it? Once you create it through powershell you should be able to go to the management portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com/) and access it there.